# Reflections and other transformations with Java Polygons

Tags: java, reflection, graphics, awt, polygon

I'm working on a project that requires me to do simple **geometrical transformations**:

- translation
- reflection over x and y axis

On some figures drawn on a `Java` applet.

The previous guy working on the applet was drawing the figures from arrays representing the caretesian points for the vertices of each figure.

I decided to represent the figures as **Polygons** because it added some nicer organization to the code, I could use the arrays he was using to construct one, and also because I figured transformations would become easier.

After finding Polygon didn't have any methods for reflection, I tried another route:

I cast the Polygon as a Shape, then an Area, and then applied a `AffineTransform` that should have done what I wanted; unfortunately, Graphics doesn't have a method to draw Area objects, and I couldn't cast back into a shape.

So, does anyone know of a way to do geometric reflection using Polygons?
Or, is there some other means through which I could perform this?

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason why you can't just write your own functions for this? Like:

```
Polygon reflectX(Polygon p) {
    Polygon np = new Polygon();
    for (int i = 0; i < p.npoints; i++) {
        np.addPoint(p.xpoints[i], -p.ypoints[i]);
    }
    return np;
}
```

Comment: Just implements methods that moves each point to right position as Jonathan just did.

Comment: My only problem is that I can't move the origin without breaking other code in the applet, so having those negative points draws the figures off of the viewable area.

Comment: But if negative points are off of the viewable area, how were you doing reflections? Perhaps what you want is actually two layers -- a back-end which does all of the calculations properly using Euclidian geometry, and a front-end that renders these to the appropriate places on the screen.

Comment: I wasn't doing reflections before, sorry for not clarifying that in the original post. That's a good idea though; I can just apply offsets to these values based on where the origin should be to ensure the figure is on the drawable area. Also, I probably should have thought of that ^_^; I'll give it a shot. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Does your viewable area shows the negative quadrants as well ? If it only show the positive x and y quadrant, every reflexion upon an axis will put your objects off grid. Unless you want to reflect uopn an axis that is not placed on the origin. Am I clear enough ?